# Linphone and Xamarin Forms; how to set remote and local views?

Tags: xamarin.forms, linphone, linphone-sdk

Based on the *Linphone* Windows 10 app [implementation](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-windows10), I am able to view remote and local video by setting the properties `Linphone.Core.NativeVideoWindowId` and `NativePreviewVideoWindowId` to the respective `Name`:s of two `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel` controls.

When using *Linphone* in a corresponding *Xamarin Android* or *iOS* app, which UI control(s) should then be used, and which control property should be used to define the `NativeVideoWindowId` and `NativePreviewVideoWindowId` on those platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the similar question.

**Android:**

```
videoView = new GL2JNIView(context);
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
```

Assigning via the custom renderer, for example `ViewRenderer<CameraPreview, Droid.Lib.CameraPreview>`

**iOS:**

```
 var wrapper = (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NativeViewWrapper)contentViewVideoParent.Content;
                var videoview = (UIView)wrapper.NativeView;
```

And assigning `IntPtr videoview.Handle` to the linphone view.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed same problem, with your answer, but I think in this example is some code missing (for next person, with the same problem), so I post the code which worked for me.

*for iOS:*

---

#### AppDelegate.cs (iOS project)

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App(IntPtr.Zero));
    View view = null;
    UIView iView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0,0,640,480));
    view = iView.ToView();
    ((App)App.Current).ViedoFrame().Content = view;
    NativeViewWrapper wrapper = (NativeViewWrapper)((App)App.Current).ViedoFrame().Content;
    UIView uiView = (UIView)wrapper.NativeView;
    ((App)App.Current).Core.NativePreviewWindowId = uiView.Handle;
    ((App)App.Current).Core.VideoDisplayEnabled = true;
    ((App)App.Current).Core.VideoPreviewEnabled = true;
    
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

#### App.cs (shared project)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    ...
    
    public Page MainPageContent;
    
    public App(IntPtr context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPageContent = new MainPage();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(MainPageContent);
    }
    
    public ContentView ViedoFrame()
    {
        return MainPageContent.FindByName<ContentView>("video_frame");
    }
    
    ...
}
```

#### MainPage.xaml (shared project)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kiwi"
             x:Class="Project.Linphone"
             Title="KiwiDoorUni">
             
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        ...
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    <StackLayout>
        ...
        <ContentView x:Name="video_frame">
        <!-- leave blank, UIView will be inserted here -->
        </ContentView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

*for android*

---

i used the code from BelledonneCommunications in the Linphone Xamarin example project and it worked for me

example project can be found here:

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-xamarin

check the file: MainActivity.cs (android project)